# Calculate maximum number of independent columns of a modular matrix

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic, matrix-rank, matrix-congruences

I have a question on determining the minimum number of dependent columns (of the maximum number of independent ones) of a matrix when the coefficients are all modulo $m\in \mathbb{N}$.
For example, take this matrix where the coefficients are modulo $13$:
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 \\
1 & 9 & 12 & 10 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 1 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to know what is the least number of dependent columns I can find. Since there are $4$ rows, I know that the maximum number of independent columns is $4$ (correct me if I'm wrong) and therefore the least number of dependent ones would be $5$, so I would just have to calculate all the possible $4\times 4$ determinants and check if they are non-zero. However, I am wondering if the fact that the top row has all $1$'s gives me some information on the problem. Since the first element is equal for all the columns, can I conclude that every $4$ columns are linearly independent? I am not sure about this, beacuse as long as I take a combination of columns like the following:
$$a_1C_1+\ldots a_jC_j\quad \mbox{where} \quad a_1+\ldots+a_j\equiv_{13}1 \quad \mbox{and} \quad  j<5$$
then I could get that this sum is another column. Can somenone help me here?

Comment: Do you recall how to compute determinants using transformations like substracting a row to other rows or so ? You can do the same manipulations here, as long as they don't change the rank of the matrix? For example using the row with only 1's. (it's a first step and not the final answer).

Comment: But indeed it may be more efficient to work on rows and not columns (the answer is the same, can you explain why ?). Also note that there is no standard solution to such exercices. Just some things that you have to try.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper is the maximum number of linearly independent columns the same as the maximum rumber of linearly independent rows?

Comment: Yes, can you explain why ?

Comment: Did you manage to find the rank of such matrix ? Did you try Gaussian elimniation ? Maybe you can post your answer if you ever find the rank.